# updating multiple fields in the table

Tags: sql, arrays

I have a table that looks like this

```
room       date         price
128     02-09-2013       15
128     03-09-2013       17
128     04-09-2013       19
```

If I want to update the field price depending on the dates,

First I have the form with the data:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($listprices))

<? $date[]=$rows[date]; ?>
<p style="width:100px;float:left;text-align:center;"><input name="price[]" type="text" value="<? echo $rows[´price´]; ?>"></p>
```

After that update sql

```
UPDATE tablename SET price='".$_POST['price'][$i]."' WHERE date='$date[$i]'";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add die(mysql_error()) http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: How is the date getting posted to the code with update query?

Comment: i keep getting the following on the input fields - Cannot use a scalar value as an array in